# From Dependency Relation to Phrase

Tags: dependencies, stanford-nlp, phrase

I'm trying to get the phrases that contain specific dependency relations. For example, I want the Noun Phrase that contains the Subject, the Noun Phrase that acts as an Appositive, etc. For example:

```
               Sentence: John Smith and Robert Alan Jones ate the warm pizza and cold salad by the car for an hour.
         Phrasal Subject: John Smith and Robert Alan Jones
                Negation: 
                   Verbs: ate
   Phrasal Direct Object: the warm pizza and cold salad
 Phrasal Indirect Object: 
               Root Noun: 
       Phrasal Root Noun: 
      Phrasal Appositive: 
Phrasal Subject Complement: 
Phrasal Object Complement: 
Phrasal Clausal Complement: 
        Adjective Phrase: warm
        Adverbial Phrase: 
   Prepositional Phrases: [by the car, for an hour]
```

Again - I'm using the Dependency Parser; I've written some code to recursively navigate the TypedDependency collection... but it feels hacky. Is there a built-in way I should be using to return phrases and word combinations (MWE, POSS, etc.) from the dependency relations??
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I think the OpenIE system is good for getting triples like this.

Here is a basic example I wrote, there may be better ways.  The containingNounPhrase method could be useful to add to Tree.  Also possibly I will add some of this to the Stanford CoreNLP 3.8.0 release.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;

public class PhraseDependencyExample {

  public static Tree containingNounPhrase(Tree tree, Tree leaf) {
    Tree currTree = leaf;
    Tree largestNPTree = null;
    while (currTree != null) {
      if (currTree.label().value().equals("NP"))
        largestNPTree = currTree;
      currTree = currTree.parent(tree);
    }
    return largestNPTree;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
    // use faster shift reduce parser
    props.setProperty("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
    props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "100");
    // set up Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // build annotation for a review
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("John Smith and Robert Alan Jones ate the warm pizza and cold salad.");
    // annotate the review
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      System.err.println("---");
      Tree sentenceConstituencyParse = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
      System.err.println(sentenceConstituencyParse);
      SemanticGraph sg = sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class);
      for (IndexedWord iw : sg.vertexListSorted()) {
        if (iw.tag().equals("VBD")) {
          System.err.println("---");
          System.err.println("verb: "+iw.word());
          for (SemanticGraphEdge sge : sg.outgoingEdgeList(iw)) {
            if (sge.getRelation().getShortName().equals("dobj") || sge.getRelation().getShortName().equals("nsubj")) {
              int tokenIndex = sge.getDependent().backingLabel().index()-1;
              String fullPhrase = containingNounPhrase(sentenceConstituencyParse,
                  sentenceConstituencyParse.getLeaves().get(tokenIndex)).yieldWords().toString();
              System.err.println("\t"+sge.getRelation() + " --> "+fullPhrase);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. This code shows how to get the leaves of the constituency tree and the vertices of the dependency parse graph.
2. It is set up to get the largest noun phrase containing the word, but you could alter it to get the smallest, etc...